# KVM: Assinging ethernet ports to a VM exclusively

Tags: linux, virtualization, linux-kvm, pfsense

I need to virtualise pfSense using KVM. Currently, pfSense running on bare metal. However, I am not sure how to go about it such that I don't create a security risk.

The machine I am running pfSense on does not support Vt-d/IOMMU, only Vt-x. If I understand this right, it means I cannot just pass control over the PCI device to pfSense, but need to use virtio to assign the ethernet interface. It has two Intel Gigabit Ethernet ports, one connected to the internet provider (WAN), the other connected to my home network (LAN).

How do I need to setup linux resp. KVM so the vm host cannot use the WAN port? I want to avoid that the linux that runs the KVM can access the WAN port directly - it should use only the LAN port and traffic to the outside should run through pfSense.

Comment: I cannot think of a way to make the host *cannot* use the "WAN port" (since you mentioned your machine cannot do PCIe passthrough), but you can use a bridged network while leaving the bridge (the host side) without any IP configuration.

Comment: @TomYan Could you make this an answer with some explanation of how to configure this?

Comment: I wrote an answer for you. But pfSense is a FreeBSD-based distro, but not Linux, and I am not familiar with (Free)BSD at all. So...see if it helps :P

Answer (score 1):

You can use a bridged network while leaving the bridge (the host side) without any IP configuration.

Note that with a bridged network, your VM will be exposed to *wherever the bridged NIC is connected to*. In your case, it would be *the Internet*. The VM will get an IP directly from your ISP (whether it's a public or private IP depends on the it).

How to do that really depends on your preference and which network agent/manager you use. So I will just present the concept with [`ip`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iproute2):

---

Create a bridge:

```
ip link add name br0 type bridge
```

Connect the NIC for the VM ("WAN port") to the bridge:

```
ip link set enp3s0 master br0
```

(replace `enp3s0` with the interface name of your "WAN port")

Create a `tap` for the VM to connect to the bridge:

```
ip tuntap add name tap0 mode tap
```

Connect the `tap` to the bridge:

```
ip link set tap0 master br0
```

To avoid any IPv6 autoconfiguration, you can use the `disable_ipv6` sysctl:

```
sysctl net.ipv6.conf.enp3s0.disable_ipv6=1
sysctl net.ipv6.conf.br0.disable_ipv6=1
sysctl net.ipv6.conf.tap0.disable_ipv6=1
```

Bring up the interfaces:

```
ip link set enp3s0 up
ip link set br0 up
ip link set tap0 up
```

---

Then you can use `-net tap` in qemu. For example, `-net tap,ifname=tap0,script=no,downscript=no`. (You can also add `,vhost=on` for better performance.)

You can actually use `,script=someup.sh,downscript=somedown.sh` to tell qemu the scripts to run respectively when the VM/tap is brought up and down. However, IMHO it is not a good way since the scripts will likely need to be run as root, so if you use these params the VM must be started as root as well. Therefore, I would rather wrap qemu like this if I want a similar approach:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo /path/to/someup.sh
qemu-system-x86_64 ...
sudo /path/to/somedown.sh
```

---

If you prefer the `tap` to be dynamically created and deleted when the VM boot up and shut down, you may want to make use of the `qemu-bridge-helper`. *To do so, skip the steps above that involve `tap`.* Instead, you need to create an access control list:

```
[tom@localhost ~]$ cat /etc/qemu/bridge.conf 
allow br0
```

Obviously, it's a list of bridge(s) that are allowed to be used by `qemu-bridge-helper`.

Once that's done, you can use `-net bridge` in qemu. You *might or might not* need to specify the bridge to use and/or the path to `qemu-bridge-helper`. For example, `-net bridge,br=br0,helper=/usr/lib/qemu/qemu-bridge-helper`.

---

Note that in addition to `-net tap` *or* `-net bridge`, you need to add a `-net nic` as well. It is about the interface presentation on the guest side. For example, `-net nic,model=virtio`. You may want to specify a MAC address with `,macaddr=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx` as well. If you do so, do NOT use any MAC address of the interfaces on the host side *that are involved* (i.e. enp3s0, br0 and tap0, in this example), otherwise it will not work. If you do not specify one, qemu will use the default `52:54:00:12:34:56`. So unless you are going to have multiple VMs that are interconnected, this is optional.